# This image could not be downloaded in android. Why?

Tags: android

I use the following code to download images. All images can be successfully downloaded except one. This image http://www.dailydealster.com/system/illustrations/18089/original/18089s.jpg could not be downloaded. Any one experience such a problem. While debugging the image is downloaded. But at release mode, this image is not downloading

```
try {
  ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
  i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If you post your error code, it'll be easier to help :)

Comment: Can you download the image with the built-in web browser applicaton?

Comment: yes..using browser the images is downloaded

Comment: whether you are getting any Error in Logcat?

Comment: no..when I debug the code, the image is downloaded. But in release mode, it is not downloading

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in the past.

```
i = Drawable.createFromStream(((InputStream) new URL(imageUrl).getContent()),"image_name.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to space out your retrieval code to something like this:

```
    URL url = new URL(photoUrl);
    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ucon.getInputStream());

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This way you avoid using casting, making it a more robust approach and could potentially solve your problem.

Comment: At run time the value of bitmap is null

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your image is too large to download it that way. Try downloading a smaller image and if it works, go and check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573175/how-can-i-fetch-a-large-image-from-a-url) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996470/load-large-image-from-server-on-android).